# jQuery plugin to put a twitter feed on my site

Tags: jquery, twitter

I want to put the first *n* entries from my twitter feed on my blog with the usual enhancements:

- Convert URLs to real links
- Remove @ replies

I realize this wouldn't be too difficult to code from scratch with `$.getJSON`, but since this sort of thing is so common, I was wondering if there was a neat plugin that would handle everything for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [Tweet](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/), with a few small modifications.

In particular, I added an option to filter @ replies and implemented it like this:

```
  // in the $.each loop over the JSON results
  if (s.ignore_at_replies === true && item.in_reply_to_user_id !== null) {
    return true;
  }
```

Reference: [Filter out @replies in a Twitter feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619773/filter-out-replies-in-a-twitter-feed)

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [jQuery plugin for Twitter](http://coda.co.za/blog/2008/10/26/jquery-plugin-for-twitter).

Answer (score 0):

There is also [jQuery Tweet Rotator](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-tweet-rotator-slideshow/full_screen_preview/262944). It's not free, but only $5.